# $f:\mathbb Z[x] \rightarrow\mathbb Z[x], f(x) = x^2$ is a ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> $f:\mathbb Z[x] \rightarrow\mathbb  Z[x], f(x) = x^2$ is a ring homomorphism?

Say I take two elements from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

i.e. Say I take

$a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... + a_n x^n$

and

$b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + ... + b_n x^n$

Is there any 'shortcut' I'm missing to proving $f$ is a ring homomorphism or will I just have to apply $f(x) = x^2$ on those elements which seems like  a bit of a nightmare.

Comment: Have you learnt about universal property of polynomial rings?

Comment: @kan nope not yet

Comment: Could I just take $x \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and then $f(x + x) = f(2x) = 4x^2 \neq f(x) + f(x) = 2x^2$. So then $f$ is not a ring homomophism?

Comment: I agree with kan. The rule $f(x)=x^2$ only applies to the polynomial $x$. We extend it so as to make it respect the ring homomorphisms, so what will happen is that $f(r(x))=r(x^2)$, or in other words:
$$f(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots +a_nx^n)=a_0+a_1x^2+a_2x^4+\cdots+a_nx^{2n}.$$

Comment: But 'normally' $f(x) = x^2$ would imply that $x$ stands for some variable in the domain, which in this case would be a polynomial of the form $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... + a_n x^n$. It seems to me the question is poorly defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you have to realize is that for a polynomial $p(x) \in {\mathbb Z}[x]$, $f(p(x)) = p(x^2)$. Then you get $f(p(x) + q(x)) = p(x^2) + q(x^2) = f(p(x)) + f(q(x))$ and similarly for the other properties of ring homomorphism that you have to verify.

*Edit*: I just realized I'm reading the question optimistically here. Literally taken, the statement $f(x) = x^2$ does not really determine $f$ fully. I more-or-less automatically took it to mean "send $x$ to $x^2$ and the rest where it should go using that", but that already assumes that $f$ is a ring homomorphism.